# embed pdf in html height doesn't streach

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to embed pdf in my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GetPDF</title>
</head>
<body>
    <object data="/Content/Exams/2016/T205_16.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I run this I'm getting width of 100% (good), but the height is only like 100px and not 100% as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default HTML block elements (including the `<html>` and `<body>` elements) are only as high as their content. That is, they 'shrink' to fit the height of their content. The PDF object has its height property set to 100%, but since this is 100% of its parent, not the viewport, and the PDF's parent is shrinking to fit content, the PDF object will display at its minimum height.

You need to set the PDF object's parent (the `<body>` elements) to be the height of the viewport. This is done easily with CSS - simply set the `<html>` element's height CSS property to 100% to make it fill the viewport, and then also set the `<body>` element's height to 100% to fill the `<html>` element.

Add this code to your `<head>`:

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```